# Using package-lock.json with version control

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, node-modules, package.json

My team is working on a react native project using GitHub for version control and we have been having a lot of issues dealing with npm dependencies. Every time we push to the master branch we keep getting conflicts with the package-lock.json file ... any best practices around that?

Comment: Do you mean "package-lock.json" or is there some other file that you have in your code called "json.lock"?

Comment: Yes, let me update. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When you install the dependencies of libraries, you need to lock down the version of them. So You should get used to the package manager like npm, yarn, ...
- I recommend use `Yarn` This is the document for how to using it. https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs
- ie: install lib react-native-button. you just need run command `yarn add react-native-button` and commit the yarn.lock with package.json files. Then the guys in your team can pull these changes and run 'yarn install' to keep the synchronize for you projects.
- Check it out and try. it is simple!

Comment: I am actually using npm already, I guessed I worded the question really badly... the issue is that we working on different parts (branch, components etc...) of the project but when we combine them we get that issue... even after I run npm ( which supposed to update and add missing dependencies) the issue persists